# Can i have boost asio socket references in two different class instances?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, move

I want to `std::move(my_asio_socket)` to the instance of some class. What if I do the same for an instance of some other class?

My purpose is to `read_async` in one class instance (let's say class `A`), and to execute `write_async` in the other (let's say class `B`). Because of some functionality implementations, I should do it this way.

Any suggestion would be nice.

**UPDATED**

it's not working properly as i expected.
The VS2015(vc14 compiler) shows me a kind of exception while debugging:

`Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> > at memory location 0x02D8E3BC.`

And after i hit `continue` in VS it show me that:

`Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.`

As i said, i'm trying to `boost::move` (or `std::move`) the socket to other class instance. Here is a snippet of code of what i'm doing:

```
boost::shared_ptr<connection> new_connection_;//it's a field in my class,
//that's why i should reset it later
new_connection_.reset(new connection(std::move(socket_), io_service_));
new_connection_->start();
```

Now here is my `connection` ctor:

```
    connection::connection(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock, boost::asio::io_service& io_ptr)
    : socket_(boost::move(sock)),
      io_ptr_(io_ptr),
      remote_ep(socket_.remote_endpoint()),
      //request_handler_(new request_handler(boost::move(socket_))),
      work(new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_ptr))
    {
      boost::shared_ptr<request_handler> req_ptr(new request_handler(boost::move(socket_)));
      request_handler_.swap(req_ptr);
    }
```

As you can see, i've tried initializing in the commented line, but it shows me the same result.
Here is the ctor for `request_handler`:

```
    request_handler::request_handler(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock):
                                           socket_(boost::move(sock)){ }
```

And here is my method `connection::start` where the problem detects:

```
void connection::start()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::keep_alive kl(true);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::enable_connection_aborted eca(true);
    // here it breaks, when trying to set an option
    socket_.set_option(eca);
    socket_.set_option(kl);

    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
        boost::bind(&connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

This problem appears only when i use to move `socket` into the new instance of `request_handler`. If i'm not - then all goes okey. I can't understand what reason it could be, but seems like my `socket_` (i declare it everywhere without any `&` or `*`) field from `connection` class is lost or kind of. But the debugger isn't showing me smthing like null, so i don't know what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In general](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) it is not guaranteed:

> Move assignment operators typically "steal" the resources held by the argument (e.g. pointers to dynamically-allocated objects, file descriptors, TCP sockets, I/O streams, running threads, etc.), rather than make copies of them, and leave the argument in some valid but otherwise indeterminate state. For example, move-assigning from a std::string or from a std::vector may result in the argument being left empty. However, this behaviour should not be relied upon.

But according to the documentation for [`tcp::socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/operator_eq_/overload1.html) it is left in the same state:

> Following the move, the moved-from object is in the same state as if constructed using the basic_stream_socket(io_service&) constructor.

Comment: thanks for answer, i thought the same way... but i was confused, because of "stolen" resources as you mentioned. I'll test it, and accept your answer after it goes ok :)

Comment: not really good news, because of it isn't working as expected. May be i'm doing something wrong? I've updated the post with some problem description. @teivaz - check it please.

Comment: I can't really tell right now what is wrong here right now. What I see is `new_connection_.reset(new connection(std::move(socket_), io_service_));` here you don't need to wrap in `std::move` as you don't have overloaded constructor `connection(socket&&, io_service&);`. I'll try to get back to it tomorrow.

Comment: ok. By the way, i've tried doing without wrapping into `move` but my intelli sense reports a error, so i must use `std::move`. May be because of `socket_` is a field in the class where i call `new_connection_.reset(new connection(std::move(socket_), io_service_));`.  Or may be do you want to say that i must receive the `socket` param in my `connection` ctor by the refference `&` ?